# Randomize question on Android Studio - Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I made a simple quiz on Android Studio which contains 8 questions. How to make the questions become random without duplicated. This app does not use a database. I'm new to programming so I don't know what to do about this

Here's the code Kuis Activity

private lateinit var kuis: TextView
private lateinit var rg: RadioGroup
private lateinit var choiceA: RadioButton
private lateinit var choiceB: RadioButton
private lateinit var choiceC: RadioButton
private lateinit var choiceD: RadioButton
private var number = 0

```
val question: Array<String> = arrayOf(
    "Mandau merupakan senjata tradisional yang berasal dari suku...",
    "Pakaian tradisional suku Madura bernama...",
    "Suku yang teridentifikasi memiliki 13 kerajaan adalah...",
    "Cheongsam merupakan pakaian tradisional dari...",
    "Lagu Jubata merupakan lagu yang berasal dari suku Dayak yang memiliki arti...",
    "Berikut ini merupakan kuliner khas Kalimantan Barat kecuali...",
    "'Takadang jantu barang dah latih'. Penggalan lirik tersebut berasal dari lagu...",
    "Rumah Adat Saoraja merupakan rumah adat yang berasal dari suku..."
)

val option = arrayOf(
    "Jawa", "Dayak", "Melayu", "Bugis",
    "Batik", "Teluk Belanga", "King Baba", "Pesa'an",
    "Jawa", "Dayak", "Melayu", "Madura",
    "Tionghoa", "Dayak", "Melayu", "Bugis",
    "Tanah", "Tuhan", "Sungai", "Keselamatan",
    "Kwetiau", "Pengkang", "Rendang", "Chai Kwe",
    "Tanah Parenean", "Jubata", "Cik Cik Periuk", "Sungai Kapuas",
    "Dayak", "Tionghoa", "Melayu", "Bugis"
)

val answer = arrayOf(
    "Dayak",
    "Pesa'an",
    "Melayu",
    "Tionghoa",
    "Tuhan",
    "Rendang",
    "Jubata",
    "Bugis"
)


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kuis)

    supportActionBar?.title = "Kuis"

    kuis = findViewById(R.id.kuis)
    rg = findViewById(R.id.pilihan)
    choiceA = findViewById(R.id.pilihanA)
    choiceB = findViewById(R.id.pilihanB)
    choiceC = findViewById(R.id.pilihanC)
    ChoiceD = findViewById(R.id.pilihanD)

    kuis.setText(question[number])
    choiceA.setText(option[0])
    choiceB.setText(option[1])
    choiceC.setText(option[2])
    choiceD.setText(option[3])

    rg.check(0)
    correct = 0
    wrong = 0


}

fun next(view: View) {
    if (choiceA.isChecked || choiceB.isChecked || choiceC.isChecked || choiceD.isChecked) {
        val userAnswer: RadioButton = findViewById(rg.checkedRadioButtonId)
        val takeUserAnswer: String = userAnswer.text.toString()
        rg.check(0)

        if (takeUserAnswer.equals(answer[number])) correct++
        else wrong++
        number++


        if (number< 8) {
            kuis.setText(question[number])
            choiceA.setText(option[(number * 4) + 0])
            choiceB.setText(option[(number * 4) + 1])
            choiceC.setText(option[(number * 4) + 2])
            choiceD.setText(option[(number * 4) + 3])
        } else {
            result = correct * 100 / 8
            val intent = Intent(this, HasilKuis::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Belum Dijawab", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inefficient way would be something like this:

```
val soal = mutableListOf<String>(...)
val indices = mutableSetOf<Int>()
do {
    val randomIndex = Random.nextInt(soal.size)
    if (randomIndex !in indices) {
        // Update views with their respective data using the randomIndex, e.g. soal[randomIndex]
        indices.add(randomIndex)
    }
} while (indices.size < 8)
```

The efficient way would be to make your arrays `MutableList<String>` and modify their size along the way:

```
val soal = mutableListOf<String>(...)
var upperBound = soal.lastIndex
do {
    val randomIndex = if (upperBound != 0) Random.nextInt(upperBound) else 0
    // Update views with their respective data using the randomIndex, e.g. soal.removeAt(randomIndex)
    upperBound--
} while (soal.isNotEmpty())
```

Comment: I tried to put your code but the app keeps closed. I don't know why

Comment: There were a few oversights, I've updated the code. Keep in mind that I'm referring to the actual question of getting items from an array/a list without repeating any items. The actual logic on how and when to use those items is up to you.